# How to visually print a n-ary tree in c#?

Tags: c#, tree

I made a basic n-ary tree in c#:

Tree:

```
public class Tree<T>
{
    private Node<T> root;

    public Tree()
    {
        root = null;
    }


    public Node<T> Root
    {
        get
        {
            return root;
        }

        set
        {
            root = value;
        }
    }

    public T search (T data)
    {
        return (root != null) ? raiz.search(data) : default(T);
    }
```

}

Node:

```
public class Node<T>
{
    private T data;
    private List<Node<T>> childs;

    public Node(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.childs = null;
    }

    public T Data
    {
        get
        {
            return data;
        }

        set
        {
            data = value;
        }
    }

    public List<NodoArbol<T>> Childs
    {
        get
        {
            return childs;
        }

        set
        {
            childs = value;
        }
    }

    public void addChild(Node node)
    {
        if (child == null)
        {
            childs = new List<Node<T>>();
        }
            childs.Add(node);

    }


    public T search(T data)
    {
        if (this.data.Equals(data))
        {
            return this.data;
        }else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < childs.Count; i++)
            {
                T aux = childs.ElementAt(i).search(data);
                if (aux != null)
                {
                    return aux;
                }
            }
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like a visual representation of the tree so that I can quickly test to see if the children and nodes are in the right place and test my traversals (pre order/in order/post order) something like this

[image]

Comment: Are you using winforms or WPF?

Comment: Do you have a question Bryan?

Comment: We're not a code-writing service even if you have provided us a data structure

Comment: Just a quick suggestion - you can define `Node<T>` simply as `public class Node<T> : List<Node<T>> { public T Data { get; private set; } public Node(T data) { this.Data = data; } }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is enough for you to output it to console:

```
public void PrintTree(Node node, int indentSize, int currentLevel)
{
    var currentNode = string.Format("{0}{1}", new string(" ",indentSize*currentLevel, node.Data);
    Console.WriteLine(currentNode)
    foreach(var child in node.Children)
    {
        PrintTree(child, indentSize, currentLevel+1);
    }
}
```

And then call it like this

```
PrintTree(yourTreeInstance.Root,4,0);
```

You also can use Debug.WriteLine to output to debug console instead of main console